# async autocomplete service

Tags: autocomplete, hashtag

Call me crazy, but I'm looking for a service that will deliver autocomplete functionality similar to Google, Twitter, etc.  After searching around for 20 min I thought to ask the geniuses here.  Ideas?

I don't mind paying, but it would great if free.. Also is there a top notch NLP service that I can submit strings to and get back states, cities, currencies, company names, establishments, etc.  Basically I need to take unstructured data (generic search string) and pull out key information with relevant meta-data.

Big challenge, I know.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing solutions I found after further research.

https://github.com/haochi/jquery.googleSuggest

http://shreyaschand.com/blog/2013/01/03/google-autocomplete-api/

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to implement it yourself, you can use this service called 'Autocomplete as a Service' which is specifically written for these purposes. You can access it here - [www.aaas.io](http://aaas.io).

you can add metadata with each record and it returns metadata along with the matching results. Do check out demo put up on the home page. It has got a very simple API specifically written for autocomplete search

It does support large datasets and you can apply filters as well while searching.

Its usage is simple - Add your data and use the API URL as autocomplete data source.

Disclaimer: I am founder of it. I will be happy to provide this service to you.